# Postgresql user-defined type and trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have user defined type in Postgresql and table with this type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.hour_integer AS
(
    q_1 integer,
    q_2 integer,
    q_3 integer,
    q_4 integer
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS device_hours_data
(
    device_hours_data_id serial,
    date date,
    h01 hour_integer ,
    h02 hour_integer ,
    h03 hour_integer ,
...
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Now I need to create a trigger before insert with rule: if h01.q_1 is null then h01.q_1 = 0. How can I use correct syntax please ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.device_hours_data_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    v_hour character varying;
BEGIN
    IF (NEW).h01.q_1 = null THEN
      NEW.h01.q_1 = 0;
    END IF;

    ...

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am using something like:

```
 NEW.h01.q_1 = 0; - syntax error,
(NEW).h01.q_1 = 0; - syntax error,
(NEW.h01).q_1 = 0; - syntax error....
```

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: I think you first need to assign the column to a local variable of your user type: `declare new_hour hour_integer; begin new_hour := new.h01; ...`

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of that custom type? Are you trying to roll your own `interval` or `time` implementation?

Comment: I have 4 value quarter numbers in one hour and 24 columns in a day in one table. But this is only example. Problem is how to assign some value into NEW.h01.q_1 in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work is as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name, something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.device_hours_data_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    v_hour character varying;
    new_hour hour_integer;
BEGIN
    new_hour = NEW.h01;
    IF new_hour.q_1 = null THEN
      new_hour.q_1 = 0;
    END IF;

    ...
    NEW.h01 = new_hour;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Great! It is working perfectly, many thanks!!!!

Comment: Will you upvote and/or accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: The answer provided by @AdrianKlaver seems to have solved your issue, so could you accept it. Doing so helps future questions with the same issue and it removes the question from the unanswered queue.  Please do not leave satisfactorily answered as unanswered.